# Setting isUserInteractionEnabled on tabBar doesn't work the first time

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a UITabBarController and do this inside one of its view controllers:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

the first time it shows, I can still change tabs.

If I tap on another tab and tap back on the first tab, then the tabbar is really disabled, but not the first time.

Why? And how do I solve this?

EDIT:

There is one detail I noticed, the `tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` has to be on the second view controller of a navigation controller. In other words:

Say I have that structure

```
UITabBarController
    UINavigationController
        UIViewController (1)
        UIViewController (2)
    UIViewController (3)
```

So if I add that `viewDidAppear` code on view controller `(2)`, you can change the tab once, but not the second time (after you navigate to it, obviously).

And there is more, if I go back after navigating to view controller `(2)`, the tab bar becomes "interactable" again, without my setting it to `true`.

Comment: try in viewWillAppear instead, for me work there

Comment: In fact for me works in viewDidAppear also, so I think there is another source for your problem

Comment: Can you post all your UITabController related code?

Comment: I'm trying to pin point the problem a little more, but there is nothing directly changing the tabbar.

Comment: Aha, got it, I'll edit my question

Comment: Then you have found the solution?

Comment: Nope =) ... Just pin pointed the problem.

Comment: I will setup and example with your current configuration for test and i will show the results

Comment: have you solved this per chance? I'm experiencing the same behavior. You can actually change the background tint of the bar in viewDidAppear() but not enable/disable it..?

Comment: Nope =/........

Answer (score 1):

Having a tab bar in view, but not being able to interact with it will probably be confusing and frustrating for the user. And while I don't have the reason or solution for the original question, I have an alternative suggestion:

> **Hide the tab bar in `UIViewController (2)`**:
>
> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>     tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
> }
> ```
>
> We're putting this in `viewDidLoad` so it's hidden as soon as the view
>   appears.

---

This also requires that you explicitly unhide it in **`UIViewController (1)`** for when the user hits the back button. Do it in viewWillAppear since the view was loaded already and we're going back to it.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Hiding and unhiding the tabBar leaves a black space at the bottom. Also, I'm not in charge of deciding the design unfortunately =/, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

While I have experienced the same behavior with:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

..what you CAN do is disable each of the items in the tabBar.items collection, and then re-enable them in the viewWillAppear method of another controller. For example, if you didn't want your users tabbing out of menu #1 once they are inside it, you could do something like this in the subsequent controller(s):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //0th tab items remains enabled as "only choice" for user
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![1].isEnabled = false
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![2].isEnabled = false
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![3].isEnabled = false
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![4].isEnabled = false
```

}

when the user tabs back to first tab (0) (or hits the back button), in that viewController's viewWillAppear method, re-enable the items:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //re-enable tab items
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![1].isEnabled = true
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![2].isEnabled = true
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![3].isEnabled = true
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![4].isEnabled = true 

}
```